# US Census API - data by census tract

Tags: api, census

Using the US [Census Tract API](http://www.census.gov/developers/data/) I can search for the age population in different parts of the country

```
http://api.census.gov/data/2010/sf1?key=[key]&get=PCT0120125&for=county:*
```

returns list of women aged 18 by county and `PCT0120021` for men.

```
[
["PCT0120125","state","county"],
["405","01","001"],
["1153","01","003"],
["163","01","005"],
["137","01","007"],
["361","01","009"],
["56","01","011"],
["137","01","013"],
...
```

How could I look up the corresponding information by Census tract?
Something like `for=tract:*` but that gives me error messages `error: unknown/unsupported geography heirarchy`.

Comment: request //api.census.gov/data/2011/acs5?get=B00001_001E&for=tract:*&in=state:02+county:170 see documentation http://api.census.gov/data/2011/acs5/geo.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to provide a state and county in your query to retrieve Census tract level information.

This does not work:

```
http://api.census.gov/data/2010/sf1?key=[key]&get= PCT0120125&for=tract:*
```

but this works:

```
http://api.census.gov/data/2010/sf1?key=[key]&get=PCT0120125&for=tract:*&in=state:02+county:170
```